# How Get equations linking elements from rules with apriori algorithm?

Tags: python, anaconda, data-mining, apriori

I have a data base from excel file, include on 75 item, I want get equation that calculate the 75th element depending on the 74 elements value.

I am using Anaconda and python to mining data and get the rule by Apriori algorithm, I get the rule but it is not useful, because it is in An incomprehensible formula, and I have one question:
* How convert the rule to equation that calculate the 75th element depending on 
 the 74 elements value?

```
#Import libraries & dataset
import pandas as pd

from apyori import apriori

number_of_raws = 4000
number_of_columns = 75

store_data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\smaol\\Aro\\1.xlsx',header=1)

#convert to list
transactions  = []

for i in range(0, number_of_raws):
    for j in range(0, number_of_columns):
        transactions.append(str(store_data.values[i,j]))

#found Rule
association_rules = apriori(transactions, min_support=0.025, min_confidence=0.5, min_lift=3, min_length=2)  
association_results = list(association_rules)
```

The result:

```
[RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'a', 'n'}), support=0.043116666666666664, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'a'}), items_add=frozenset({'n'}), confidence=1.0, lift=23.192887514495556), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'n'}), items_add=frozenset({'a'}), confidence=1.0, lift=23.192887514495556)])]
[RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'a', 'n'}), support=0.043116666666666664, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'a'}), items_add=frozenset({'n'}), confidence=1.0, lift=23.192887514495556), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'n'}), items_add=frozenset({'a'}), confidence=1.0, lift=23.192887514495556)])]
[RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'a', 'n'}), support=0.043116666666666664, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'a'}), items_add=frozenset({'n'}), confidence=1.0, lift=23.192887514495556), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'n'}), items_add=frozenset({'a'}), confidence=1.0, lift=23.192887514495556)])]
[RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'a', 'n'}), support=0.043116666666666664, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'a'}), items_add=frozenset({'n'}), confidence=1.0, lift=23.192887514495556), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'n'}), items_add=frozenset({'a'}), confidence=1.0, lift=23.192887514495556)])]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please consider formatting your code (placing four spaces before every code line) to make it easier for potential answerers to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you always have exactly the same number of rows, this most likely is not "market basket" data. There probably is value to the position information that is *lost* when you transform this to itemsets.

What about using a standard prediction algorithm. Such as decision trees and random forests?

Don't use "apyrori". It's an incorrect implementation.